# npm Error EEXIST when trying to install babel-preset-es2015 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I get this error when trying to install babel-preset-es2015 using npm on Windows 10.

> (node:8392) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
>
> npm WARN package.json phone_app@1.0.0 No description
>
> npm WARN package.json phone_app@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> npm WARN package.json phone_app@1.0.0 No README data
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
>   "C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "babel-preset-es2015" "--save""
>
> npm ERR! node v6.2.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.0.2
>
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\b8917239--cache-lodash-4-13-1-package-tgz.lock
>
> npm ERR! code EEXIST
>
> npm ERR! errno -4075
>
> npm ERR! syscall open
>
> npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, open 'C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\b8917239--cache-lodash-4-13-1-package-tgz.lock'
>
> File exists: C:\Users\Alejandro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\b8917239--cache-lodash-4-13-1-package-tgz.lock
>
> Move it away, and try again.

Edit: I already tried deleting that file, unbuilding, trying again and it throws the same error.

npm version: 2.0.2
node js version: 6.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when install babel-preset-es2015 in WebStorm terminal.

Then i open NodeJS console and run npm install babel-preset-es2015. It was installed successfully.

Comment: Ok i tried installing it on another computer (Windows 7) with a different version of node js and it worked,so it seems the problem is either the OS or the Nodejs version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> To do this add the following lines to your ~/.npmrc and run npm
>   install again.

```
; avoid EEXIST lock errors
cache-lock-wait=30000  
cache-lock-retries=10  
cache-lock-stale=300000
```

From https://divhide.com/2016/06/12/avoiding-npm-install-eexist-lock-errors/

Comment: Where is npmrc?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of older version of npm. Update your npm and retry
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11343